# Extract only rows where certain word does not exists

Tags: regex

I need to extract only those rows where it starts with 8 digits and a space and then 2 digits and ignore the word **TDS**

**Input**

```
91298254 02/07/2021 91298254 3181753640RE,MAN-1 200,000.00
91298254 20/09/2021 TDS -577.19
91298268 03/07/2021 91298268 3181753647RE,MAN-2 166,861.00
91298268 20/09/2021 TDS -130.37
```

**Output**

```
91298254 02/07/2021 91298254 3181753640RE,MAN-1 200,000.00
91298268 03/07/2021 91298268 3181753647RE,MAN-2 166,861.00
```

I have tried `\b\d{8} \d{2}.*` and it gives me all rows with 8 digits space and another 2 digits.

Need you advice here.

Regards,
Manjesh

Comment: Your statement "I need to extract only those rows where it starts with 8 digits and a space and then 2 digits and ignore the word TDS" does not match your requirement. Would be clearer to say: "I need to convert like this example (Removing rows with 8 digits, space, date, TDS ..."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```js
^\d{8} \d{2}(?!.*\bTDS\b).*
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/FI7lEc/1/). *Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `\d{8} \d{2}` - eight digits, space, two digits
- `(?!.*\bTDS\b)` - a negative lookahead that fails the match if there are zero or more chars other than line break chars as many as possible followed with `TDS` as a whole word immediately to the right of the current location
- `.*` - the rest of the line.

Answer (score 0):

This can work, to catch lines with TDS in them

```
(?<=^|\n).*TDS.*(?=\n|$)
```

[Regex 101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/iVqFM6/1)

Answer (score 0):

```js
const str =   `91298254 02/07/2021 91298254 3181753640RE,MAN-1 200,000.00
91298254 20/09/2021 TDS -577.19
91298268 03/07/2021 91298268 3181753647RE,MAN-2 166,861.00
91298268 20/09/2021 TDS -130.37`

const result = str.replace(/(^|\n)\d{8}\s+\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4}\s+TDS[^\n]*/g, '')
console.log(result)
```